# C++ Linked List: Node Creation Function

Tags: c++, data-structures

So, I'm learning C++ and data structures. The first one I wanted to do was singly-linked lists. I created/copied the following code:

```
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

Node* head = NULL;

void createnode(int* value) {
    Node* new_node = new Node(); //allocate memory size of node
    new_node->data = *value; //data is given
    new_node->next = head;  //*next pointer is to head
    head = new_node;
}

void printlist(Node* n) {
    while (n != NULL) {
        cout << n->data << "\n";
        n = n->next;
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to visualise these two lines:

```
    new_node->next = head;  //*next pointer is to head
    head = new_node;
```

The 'next' node pointer, in the new node, is being set to 'head' of the linked list which is fine (I'm visualizing the node being inserted on the left side of 'head' and moving everything to the right, including this 'head' object). Then, in the next line, head is being set to 'new_node'.

So, it's created some sort of cyclical connection? Should the 'head' of this linked list not act as a sort of snake's head, with the values being added on behind, increasing the length of the snake, if you will.

Comment: ***So, it's created some sort of cyclical connection?*** No. You are just adding nodes at the front instead of the end.

Comment: _The first one I wanted to do was singly-linked lists. I created/copied the following code_ Bad luck. This is not what I would call idiomatic C++ code...

Comment: `new_node->next = head;` The `next` pointer of the `new_node` is set to the pointer stored in `head`. Now, `new_node->next` (and `head`) point to the currently first node of your list. `head = new_node;` Now, `head` is overridden to point to the new node. No cycle in node pointers. From now on the new node is the head of your list.

Comment: To master the magic of pointers (and lists), try on paper (with pencil and eraser) where the nodes are boxes and the pointers are arrows. That's old-fashioned but somehow still effective... ;-)

Comment: I'd recommend you first try to visualize the linked list data structure using a pencil and a sheet of paper like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck91t.png). This will make it easier to understand what's going on in a concrete implementation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This image should have had white background (but seems to be transparent instead). In my browser, it appeared with black arrows on black background... (It reminds me to the "East Frisian National Flag".)

Comment: @Scheff Should I pick another one of the umpteen gazillion images available with a [5 secs google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=linked+list+diagram&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE833DE833&sxsrf=ALeKk02uJ79nkTzU3_vnlEmPAYpt4qr9VQ:1603725853409&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfxLyuyNLsAhXRqqQKHehaA4UQ_AUoAXoECBsQAw&biw=1600&bih=789)? It's still good enough :-P

Comment: Please, note that I took the effort to translate "East Frisian National Flag" (with the help of deepl.com). I assume you know that joke (even in Bavaria or even especially there). ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Who do you think invented that joke? It was the bavarians ;-)

Comment: `head` is not an object, `head` is a pointer to an object. And it can be set to point to another object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a sequence:

```
  a -> b -> c -> NULL; // where head points to a
```

what those lines are doing is (suppose you want to add 'd' to the previous list):

```
 d -> a; // where a still points to wherever it used to point
```

and after that you update to where HEAD should point, which is no longer the node that had **a**, but the one that has **d**